# Get rows in which any column contains sequence using exists select 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns with the following values ([dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4426f79443c6766ddf367102a14c95e))

```
C1      C2         C3
----------------------------
Red     Yellow     Blue
null    Red        Green
Yellow  null       Violet
```

I'm trying to create a query that returns all the rows that contain the value "Yellow" without using `IN` or `OR`. If I execute the following query:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM test 
WHERE CONCAT(C1, C2, C3) LIKE '%Yellow%'
```

It correctly returns the rows specified. However, if I try to use this query inside an `exists`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE CONCAT(C1, C2, C3) LIKE '%Yellow%')
```

it returns all the rows, not just the two with the "Yellow" word. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the second query, you aren't correlating the `exists` subquery back to the outer query, so provided that there's at least one row with `Yellow` anywhere in the table, then all rows will be returned. You likely don't want to be using `CONCAT` and `LIKE` on large tables for performance reasons. Perhaps this is a job for [FULL TEXT SEARCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017), or another tool altogether like ElasticSearch?

Comment: What is you expect result?

Comment: @StuartLC Thanks for the tip. I was trying this query just to understand properly the use of `exist (Select 1 ...`, which I don't.

Comment: @D-Shih My expected result would be just the rows 1 and 3, the ones that contain the word "yellow" on any of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exists` clause check specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

so  `exists (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE CONCAT(C1, C2, C3) LIKE '%Yellow%')` will always have rows when any column contain `yellow` data.

if you want to use `exists` you need to set inner `exists` query  `CONCAT(t.C1, t.C2, t.C3)` by the outer table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test t 
where exists (SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE CONCAT(t.C1, t.C2, t.C3) LIKE '%Yellow%')
```

You don't need to use `exists`  only set the condition on `where`

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
where CONCAT(C1, C2, C3) LIKE '%Yellow%'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=91a72425837926257e7af4401d0c6e28)

Answer (score 2):

**Re**

```
SELECT 1 FROM test WHERE CONCAT(C1, C2, C3) LIKE '%Yellow%'
```

> "correctly returns the rows specified"

The select returns a single column, `1`, although this is because there is a row which has one column containing `Yellow` somewhere in its text.

This is because [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns TRUE if a subquery contains any rows.

i.e. All of the following queries also returned all rows in your `test` table:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1);

SELECT * FROM test WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 0);

SELECT * FROM test WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL);
```

... simply because the `SELECT` returns at least one row!

The usual usage of `EXISTS` also includes correlation of the subquery in the `EXISTS` back to the outer select.

**Example of Correlation**

In the below contrived example, we've got 4 people living in two houses. Here we're using `EXISTS` to figure out the names of the persons who are happy, and also have someone **else** who is also happy living in the same (correlated) House.

```
CREATE TABLE House
(
    HouseId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE Person
(
    PersonId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    HouseId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES HOUSE(HouseId),
    Name VARCHAR(MAX),
    IsHappy BIT
);

INSERT INTO House(HouseId, Name) VALUES (1, 'House1'), (2, 'House2');

INSERT INTO Person(PersonId, HouseId, Name, IsHappy) VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Joe', 0), 
(2, 1, 'Jim', 1),
(3, 2, 'Fred', 1),
(4, 2, 'Mary', 1);

SELECT pOuter.Name
FROM Person pOuter
WHERE pOuter.IsHappy = 1
AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
        FROM Person pInner 
        WHERE pInner.HouseId = pOuter.HouseId 
        AND pInner.PersonId != pOuter.PersonId
        AND pInner.IsHappy = 1);
```

Returns

```
Mary
Fred
```

(There are obviously other ways to find the same result, e.g. finding groupings of House Id where there exists 2 or more happy people, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @yet_another_programmer I've added a more usual example of how exists would be used. Unfortunately SqlFiddle seems down right now.

Comment: Now everything is much clearer. Thank you very much again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cross apply`:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM test t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM (VALLUES (C1), (C2), (C3)) V(C)
      WHERE c = 'Yellow'
     ) v
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

You can readily adapt this to a subquery:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM test t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (VALLUES (C1), (C2), (C3)) V(C)
              WHERE c = 'Yellow'
             ) ;
```

Personally, I much prefer the direct comparison of each value to `'Yellow'` rather than using `LIKE`.  For instance, this will not match "yellow-green" or any other value where "yellow" is part of the name.

And, just for the record, you can still use boolean logic, even if you don't use `OR` and `IN`:

```
where not (coalesce(c1, '') <> 'Yellow' and
           coalesce(c2, '') <> 'Yellow' and
           coalesce(c3, '') <> 'Yellow' 
          )
```

Technically, this is probably the "simplest" solution to your problem.  However, I still prefer the `apply` method, because the intent is clearer.